# Java EE web application Tests JPA EJB3

Tags: java, postgresql, glassfish, war

I am using an EJB3 DAOFacade inside a JSF Managed bean to pull data from database. It worked for the first launch of the server but after that it keeps printing this message error which i don't understand. Could anybody please tell me what is going on ?

```
WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on
EJB AirportFacade, method: public java.util.List
com.procc.flams.dao.AbstractFacade.findAll() WARNING:
javax.ejb.EJBException      at
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173.findAll(Unknown Source)      at
com.procc.flams.backing.AirportController.getItems(AirportController.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)   at
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)       at
com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)      at
com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at
javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)       at
org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:786)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeAttributes(DevTools.java:375)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeStart(DevTools.java:424)
    at
com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeComponent(DevTools.java:245)
    at
com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeComponent(DevTools.java:264)
    at
com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeComponent(DevTools.java:264)
    at
com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeComponent(DevTools.java:264)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.debugHtml(DevTools.java:128)
    at
com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.renderHtmlErrorPage(RenderKitUtils.java:1162)
    at
com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:276)
    at
com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)        at
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)       at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)         at
com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at
com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to
load resource [org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl$1], because it
has not yet been started, or was already stopped    at
org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
    at
org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendQueryPreamble(QueryExecutorImpl.java:432)
    at
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:252)
    at
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    at
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy180.executeQuery(Unknown Source)         at
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2031)  at
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1832)
    at
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)         at
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)         at
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)        at
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)  at
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)  at
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)     at
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at
org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1247)       at
org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)   at
org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:264)       at
org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getResultList(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:254)
    at com.procc.flams.dao.AbstractFacade.findAll(AbstractFacade.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at
org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at
com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 59 more
```

in JSF page:

```
     <p:panel header="Airports list">
         <p:dataTable value="#{airportController.items}" var="item">
         <p:column>
             <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
             <h:outputText value="#{item.airportId}"/>
         </p:column>
```

JSF code which generates the error:

```
 public List<Airport> getItems() {
     if(items==null){
         items = airportFacade.findAll();
     }
     return items;
 }
```

and Persistence code (I am using Hibernate 4.1 as JPA Provider):

```
 public List<T> findAll() {
     javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
     cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
     return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
 }
```

Comment: Specify your exact Java, Glassfish, PgJDBC and PostgreSQL versions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part of the exception appears to be:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to
load resource [org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl$1], because it
has not yet been started, or was already stopped    at
org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1401)
    at
org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendQueryPreamble(QueryExecutorImpl.java:432)
    at
```

PgJDBC tries to load a class and the custom Glassfish classloader chokes on it.

I suggest that you turn this into a minimal self-contained test case that can be compiled and run standalone, then submit it as a posssible Glassfish bug. The test case is vital; if they can't reproduce it they can't act on it.

The only other things I can think of is that you might have more than one PgJDBC version in your claasspath; you might be using the v4 JDBC driver on an ancient Java that only understands JDBCv3 and Glassfish is masking the real error; or you might be using the latest v4 driver (which is 1.7-only due to a build problem) with Java 1.6.

Comment: Hi Craig, Thanks for help. I think the problem was due to missing PostgreSQLDriver jar because i can't reproduce it anymore. I think i remembered to add that jar after posting the message.
Sorry for wasting your time and thaks again.

Comment: @velocity Well, might as well accept the answer. (green tick). BTW, you don't seem to have accepted any past answers to your questions either; take a look at your user profile page.